# Regex to identify C# functions

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio, text

I need to find all functions in my VS solution with a certain attribute and insert a line of code at the end and at the beginning of each one. For identifying the functions, I've got as far as

```
\[attribute\]\r?\n(.*)void(.*)\r?\n.*\{\r?\n([^\{\}]*)\}
```

But that only works on functions that don't contain any other blocks of code delimited by braces. If I set the last capturing group to `[\s\S]` (all characters), it simply selects all text from the start of the first function to the end of the last one. Is there a way to get around this and select just one whole function?

Comment: What if a function is *commeted out*, e.g. `// void DoIt()` or `/* void DoIt() */`. Other possibility if "function" is a part of a `string`, e.g. `String St = "void DoIt() {return;}";` Use *parser*, RegEx is not enough

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use assembly weaving instead? Like writing a Fody plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid balancing constructs themselves are not enough since you may have unbalanced number of them in the method body. You can still try this regex that will handle most of the caveats:

```
\[attribute\](?<signature>[^{]*)(?<body>(?:\{[^}]*\}|//.*\r?\n|"[^"]*"|[\S\s])*?\{(?:\{[^}]*\}|//.*\r?\n|"[^"]*"|[\S\s])*?)\}
```

See [demo on RegexStorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5C%5Battribute%5C%5D(%3F%3Csignature%3E%5B%5E%7B%5D*)(%3F%3Cbody%3E(%3F%3A%5C%7B%5B%5E%7D%5D*%5C%7D%7C%2F%2F.*%5Cr%3F%5Cn%7C%22%5B%5E%22%5D*%22%7C%5B%5CS%5Cs%5D)*%3F%5C%7B(%3F%3A%5C%7B%5B%5E%7D%5D*%5C%7D%7C%2F%2F.*%5Cr%3F%5Cn%7C%22%5B%5E%22%5D*%22%7C%5B%5CS%5Cs%5D)*%3F)%5C%7D&i=%20%20%20%5Battribute%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20public%20static%20void%20Main%20(string%5B%5D%20args)%0D%0A%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(test%20%3D%3D%20%22%7Bnew%7D%22)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20My%20God%2C%20it%20is%20crazy!%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20string%20tt%20%3D%20%22We%20just%20have%20one%20%7B%20here!%22%3B%20%2F%2F%20and%20%7B%20here%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%7D%20%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%5Battribute%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20public%20static%20void%20New%20(string%5B%5D%20args)%0D%0A%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Some%20comment%0D%0A%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(test%20%3D%3D%20%22%7Bnew%7D%22)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20My%20God%2C%20it%20is%20crazy!%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20string%20tt%20%3D%20%22We%20just%20have%20one%20%7B%20here!%22%3B%20%2F%2F%20and%20%7B%20here%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%7D%20)

The regex will ignore all `{` and `}` in the string literals and `//`-like comments, and will consume `{...}` blocks. The only thing it does not support is `/*...*/` multiline comments. Please let me know if you also need to account for them.

[image]

Comment: Am I doing something wrong? Your demo shows 0 results for me, both on your own example and if I feed it some of my own code.

Comment: I do not know why you get 0 results, I have pasted the result table into the answer.

Comment: This finds 0 methods for me as well.

Comment: @Jammer Show your code with a test case via any code sharing site, and I'll be glad to show where it goes wrong.

Comment: I have had to change the RegEx a little as I cannot always rely on there being an attribute applied to the method. https://dotnetfiddle.net/WC4pAs

Comment: @Jammer OK, `protected static (bool valid, List<ValidationProperty> errors) IsValidModel(object model){}` is OK, and `return new JsonHttpStatusResult($"Model must be set to a valid {model.GetType().Name}", 400);` contains an interpolated string literal. `\{[^}]*\}` does not match it properly as the string literal contains `{` and `}`. The fix would be to match all kinds of C# syntax constructs, and this is hard to be coded in a single regex. For cases like this, you'd need a dedicated parser.

Comment: Could you please show entire code as how do you enter the input ?

Comment: @SiddhiDilipKamat If you mean how to run the regex search in C#, Jammer [has posted a [link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WC4pAs) in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31068870/regex-to-identify-c-sharp-functions/31069671?noredirect=1#comment103429869_31069671).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I am trying to find function blocks in  entire mvc project. Will regex be the best solution ? Is there any other alternatives?

Comment: @SiddhiDilipKamat I doubt that. You should dig in the direction of Resharper.

Answer (score 0):

The bad news is that you can't do that by the Search-And-Replace feature because it doesn't support balancing groups. You can write a separate program in C# that does it for you.

The construct to get the matching closing brace is:

```
(?=\{)(?:(?<open>\{)|(?<-open>\})|[^\{\}])+?(?(open)(?!))
```

This matches a block of `{...}`. But as @DmitryBychenko mentioned it doesn't respect comments or strings.